# How I can run while loop with PyQt5

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, pyqt5

I work on one Project : Program download but I have a problem with while loop for check the connection with the internet and if true doesn't setText('') to lable and if Flase setText('anyText') to lable

**Method for check the connection**

```
    def checkInternetConnection(self,host="8.8.8.8", port=53, timeout=3):

    while self.conection==False:
        try:
            socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)
            socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect((host, port))
            self.conection = True
            return self.conection

        except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                self.label_9.setText('Please Check Internect Connection')
                self.conection = False
                return self.conection
    self.finished.emit()
```

I have tired with QThread . Please How I can do it :) ? And when app is running if connection is lost=False setText('check internet') and when the connection become true setText('')

**CONSTRUCTOR**

```
From_Class,_=loadUiType(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'designe.ui'))
class mainApp(QMainWindow,From_Class):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(mainApp, self).__init__(parent)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        super().setupUi(self)
        self.handleGui()
        self.handleButton()
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('mainIcon.png'))
        self.menuBarW()
        self.conection = False
```

**MainCode**

```
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = mainApp()
    window.checkInternetConnection()
    window.show()
    app.exec()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not get complicated with QThread, use the threading library:

```
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = mainApp()
    threading.Thread(target=window.checkInternetConnection, daemon=True).start()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

On the other hand, since you are using a thread, you should not update the GUI from another thread, for this you can use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`:

```
def checkInternetConnection(self,host="8.8.8.8", port=53, timeout=3):
    while True:
        try:
            socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)
            socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect((host, port))
            self.conection = True
        except Exception as e:
            self.conection = False
            print(e)
        msg = "" if self.conection else 'Please Check Internect Connection'
        print("msg", msg)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self.label_9, "setText",
            QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection,  
            QtCore.Q_ARG(str, msg))
    self.finished.emit()
```

Comment: Thank you bro , but I want it method checkInternetConnection is running while the app is show , So if the connection is lost false setText('Please .. ') and if connection come back setText('') :)

Comment: @Mo7ammed7amad 
Okay, I'm based on your logic, but hey, I'll correct it

Comment: Thanks bro , but there is a problem , and it's when first run the code work good , but i try when app running make disconnection with internet and the message doesn't pup-up the message :)  Is there any solution . Thank you

Comment: @Mo7ammed7amad I have tested it: 1) I started the application with internet connection, then I deactivate the internet and the message appears, if I activate the connection the message disappears. 2) start the application without internet connection so the message appears, then activate the internet and the message disappears, if I deactivate the connection the message reappears. I think the problem is elsewhere (Note: I have deleted the lines: `self.handleGui() ... self.menuBarW()` since they are irrelevant to my test)